# include navigation bar blade in other blades make "CSS" conflict in "Laravel"!

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a navigation blade template, and should include this blade to all blade files.

When I include this, The elements of my navigation blade get CSS styles from other blade files  and mutually other blades get the CSS styles of navigation blade. If I am not mistaken, a CSS conflict happens.

Is it possible to force elements receive/not receive CSS styles from a source!?
its my master blade:

```
<html lang="{{php app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

{{-- Part: all meta-related contents --}}
@yield('head-meta')

{{-- Part: site title with default value in parent --}}
@section('head-title')
    <title>Site title</title>
@stop
{{-- Part: load fonts --}}
@yield('head-fonts')
{{-- Part: load styles for the page --}}
@yield('head-styles')
{{-- Part: load scripts needed --}}
@yield('head-scripts')
{{-- Part: anything else in head --}}
@yield('head-extra')
</head>

<body>

{{-- Part: something at start of body --}}
@yield('body-start')

{{-- Part: header of body --}}
@section('body-header')
    {{-- Part: navigation bar --}}
    @include('navbar')
@show

{{-- Part: create main content of the page --}}
@yield('body-content')

{{-- Part: footer --}}
@section('body-footer')
    {{-- Part: footer is probably shared across many pages --}}
    {{--@include('partials.footer')--}}
@show

{{-- Part: load scripts --}}
@yield('body-scripts')
{{-- Part: something else to do --}}
@yield('body-others')
{{-- Part: finalize stuffs if there is --}}
@yield('body-end')

</body>
</html>
```

and its my home blade:

```
@extends('master')
@section('head-title')
    <title>{{__('messages.title')}}</title>
@stop

@section('head-styles')
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/en/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Definity CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/en/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/en/responsive.css">
@stop


@section('body-content')
    <!-- ========== Preloader ========== -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <img src="/images/loader.svg" alt="Loading...">
    </div>
@stop

@section('body-scripts')
    <!-- ========== Scripts ========== -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Definity JS -->
    <script src="js/hero/main.js"></script>
@endsection
```

finally this is my navigation bar (navbar) blade:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-5.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/languageSwitcher.css">

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>

   <title>{{__('messages.title')}}</title>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
*
*
*
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: you can force to use css you want by !important

Comment: Do you have a master layout for your pages ?

Comment: Post your views master views and child too, so we can help you

Comment: @romaltandel means i get inline css to all elements?
elements give CSS from another source, if i want set inline CSS for every element the code will be complex.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi yes i have, but when include the navbar, the CSS files of navbar are also included to other blades, and the CSS styles destroy.

Comment: @romaltandel, !important would work, but it's not as clean of a solution as being more specific in the CSS selectors.  Too much reliance on !important can make projects a challenge to maintain as they grow, IMO.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz i added codes, thank's for your helping. i'm waiting for your solution.

Comment: @romaltandel ok, but whats the solution of my problem!? is possible to solve this problem without using important!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this as well, but I strongly recommend that you create some separation in your CSS so that this does not conflict with any other page rules.

You could isolate your navbar styles by class or id.  Since you only would have one navbar, id might be a good choice:

```
#navbar a...
#navbar p...
#navbar .theclass...
#navbar > .childelement...
etc
```

In this way, only children of the element with the id of navbar would get these styles.  Also, because you have specified the id of the navbar parent, this makes it more specific compared to rules where you are targeting all anchors or all paragraphs.  If you still have conflicting rules coming in, then you could mark them unset in your navbar-specific CSS, or change them to whatever you like.

Comment: thank you so much, your answer helped me a lot, but for basic tags like <body> or <img> Still conflict happen.

by changing the class names, the conflict of navigation blade was eliminated, but for home blade the conflict is still exist.

i think because the navigation blade has been added first, they(navigation CSS files) have higher priority than home blade CSS files, and this cause conflict. but unfortunately i have no idea about this.

are you have any idea for solve this!?

Thank you.

Comment: An html page should only ever have one body tag (and one html tag too).  It sounds like you might be including a full-fledged html page with it's own body tag as the navigation blade.  In this case, you could put your html and body tags in the home blade file, and include the navigation blade right after the opening body tag in the home blade file.  Then, remove any html or body tags from the navigation blade.  If you need to keep these nav elements inside something, just use a div in place of the body tag.

Comment: My problem was solved. I don't know how to thank you.
Thank you for your all your help.